# onClickListener crashing Android app

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener

I'm writing a basic note taking app and I'm trying to implement a loading function from a ListView. The following code is from the loading function that fills out and listens for clicks on the ListView.

```
for(String tmpf : fileNames) {
    ListView notesList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listNotes);
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Object>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, fileNames);
    notesList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "-1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    notesList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentAdapter, View view, int position, long id) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            TextView clickedView = (TextView) view;
            String loadLabel = clickedView.getText().toString();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(openFileInput(loadLabel)));
                String line = null;

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line).append("\n");
                }
            } catch(OutOfMemoryError om) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error loading note - Out of Memory", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                om.printStackTrace();
            } catch(Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error loading note - Exception", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "4", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            String notes = sb.toString();
            EditText noteLabelField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editHeading);
            EditText textField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editNote);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "5", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            noteLabelField.setText(loadLabel);
            textField.setText(notes);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "6", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    notesList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parentAdapter, View view, int position, long id) {
            TextView clickedView = (TextView) view;
            deleteFile(clickedView.getText().toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Note deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

The issue is that the activity crashes as soon as I click on anything in the list. Using the Toast function, I put some alerts in and I only make it to "-1". I can't even get to the next Toast which is as soon as an item is clicked.

What's even more strange, is the long click listener at the end of the code above works perfectly.

Any ideas?

Here are the error lines from the LogCat:

```
05-10 13:00:58.420: D/AndroidRuntime(781): Shutting down VM
05-10 13:00:58.420: W/dalvikvm(781): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
05-10 13:00:58.440: E/AndroidRuntime(781): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-10 13:00:58.440: E/AndroidRuntime(781): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-10 13:00:58.440: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at com.example.mobileappassessment.LoadActivity$1.onItemClick(LoadActivity.java:105)
05-10 13:00:58.440: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
05-10 13:00:58.440: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
05-10 13:00:58.440: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2749)
05-10 13:00:58.440: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3423)
05-10 13:00:58.440: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
05-10 13:00:58.440: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-10 13:00:58.440: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-10 13:00:58.440: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-10 13:00:58.440: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-10 13:00:58.440: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-10 13:00:58.440: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-10 13:00:58.440: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-10 13:00:58.440: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what the line at LoadActivity.java:105?

Comment: I think the `NullPointerException` in the log should ring a bell. Something is `null` where it should not be. The rest of the log will help you see where exactly this happened. I'd advise you to put more attention to the logs and to use debug tools. It will be helpful to you and also will allow you to better describe your problem if you cannot solve it alone.

Comment: Line 105 is this:

    noteLabelField.setText(loadLabel)

Comment: I think I've realised what the problem is. I'm trying to set the text boxes on the activity that launches the load activity. Is it possible to return the two variables to the parent activity so that it can fill in the text boxes with their respective contents.

Comment: yes, use startActivityForResult

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Answer (score 0):

This is not good to call `findViewById`in onClickListener.

Try to create private field `EditText noteLabelField` in your activity, fill it 
`EditText noteLabelField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editHeading);` in `onCreate` and use reference `noteLabelField` in onClickListener

Answer (score 0):

The answer is staring at ya. The `loadlabel` is the one causing the trouble I believe but please post the entire log cat which might specify the line of `NullPointerException` and please make sure that `loadlabel` is not null when it enters `BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(openFileInput(loadLabel)));`. Try printing the loadlabel before sending it to the BufferedReader and do declare all the needed variables globally so that you dont use `findViewById` inside `onClicks`. Try these, they might work. Happy Coding.